# Intellij color scheme remove white lines

Tags: intellij-idea, color-scheme

[image: PrintScreen]

I have this problem with the import of the color scheme `Atom One Dark` on Intellij Ultimate Edition.

I want to *remove* that white line on the right , anyone have any tips?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are called **guidelines**, they show how long one line of code should be. To remove them do the following:

Go to Settings | Editor | Colors and Fonts | General, select "Right margin", uncheck the checkbox for "Foreground".

Comment: True, sorry about that, yeah, it's annoying when the links in answers are unavailable. Fixed it.